# What are the inconveniences of replacing a router by a computer?

Tags: networking, routing

I need to **manage the internet usage** of all the computers (between 10-50) in a network with **deeper capabilities** than those that a classical router offers.

I would like to have features like:

- Bandwith reports and stats.
- Balance of bandwith (reduce speed for some computers and increaso anothers).
- Traffic flow inspection.

So, it seems clear that I need a (probably dedicated) **computer acting as the router**.

I am ready to install Ubuntu or some other Linux distro, and I was wondering if there is any "stucking" (say "big") **inconvenience** in this change.

I (think I) know about the obvious, like:

- The computer is more expensive.
- The computer is bigger, takes more space in the room.
- The computer is harder to configure and (maybe) to manage.

but I believe I will be capable of deal with all these.

So, is there any **big problem with such change**?

Comment: This will probably get closed as a 'shopping recommendation' but have a look at Sophos UTM - freeware for I think up to 50 seats - that's what I use here. http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-utm-home-edition.aspx Hardware requirements, 1 computer, 2 NICs.

Comment: @Tetsujin, the original question asks about possible big **inconveniences** with such a network scheme, not about software.